# Error when installing python3 packages in alpine

Tags: python, docker, alpine-linux

I am currently building an image from alpine:3.7.

There are two packages that I am having problems with:

- pendulum (specifically **python-dateutils** package)
- service_identity (specifically **attrs** package)

The error that I receive it is:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for setuptools

Note: all packages are pre-cached on a directory using pip download.

The dockerfile looks as follows:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps <dev packages>
 && apk add --no-cache --update python3
 && pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools

RUN pip3 install -f ./python-packages --no-index -r requirements.txt ./python-packages/pkgs

....
```

dev-packages such as libffi-dev, libressl-dev, etc.

Comment: Please add `requirements.txt` to the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apparently when upgrading pip with:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools
```

I removed pip upgrading and installation worked. Now, I have been researching the correct way to upgrade pip on alpine and found a Dockerfile in a [github repo](https://github.com/frol/docker-alpine-python3/blob/master/Dockerfile) that does this check:

```
if [ ! -e /usr/bin/pip ]; then ln -s pip3 /usr/bin/pip ; fi && \
if [[ ! -e /usr/bin/python ]]; then ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python; fi && \
```

Which makes sure that **pip3** is being referred when calling just **pip** command by doing a symbolic link on python and system binaries' directories.

Answer (score 18):

I'm not sure about the full list of dev-packages to build in the question, but it should be the following: `g++` (GNU C++ standard library and compiler), `python3-dev` (python3 development files), `libffi-dev` (libffi development files) and `openssl-dev` (Toolkit for SSL v2/v3 and TLS v1 development files).

The `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM alpine:3.7
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps g++ python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev && \
    apk add --no-cache --update python3 && \
    pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools
RUN pip3 install pendulum service_identity
```

Comment: As commented above, those packages are not the problem. Setuptools it is the one marked as not found.

Comment: Thank you so much. Been trying to fix this on my iPad Air (ISH alpine linux x86 emulator) for 3 days. Except that I didn't upgrade pip because it will only work in version 21.1.1 for some reason.

Comment: For those having the `requires PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly` error, this will help too