# Alternate Libraries for libsm6 libxext6 libxrender1 in alpine

Tags: docker, opencv, dockerfile, python-3.6, alpine-linux

I'm trying to deploy my flask application and decided to package it with docker. 
My Docker file:

```
FROM python:3.6.8-alpine3.8

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add libsm6 libxext6 libxrender1

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]

CMD [ "server.py" ]
```

I'm using alpine as my base image. My project uses OpenCV, which requires the libraries `libsm6 libxext6` and `libxrender1`. Is there any alternate libraries available for this in alpine ?

Logs:

```
$ docker build -t flask-alpine:latest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  6.947MB
Step 1/9 : FROM python:3.6.8-alpine3.8
3.6.8-alpine3.8: Pulling from library/python
c87736221ed0: Pull complete
c3f51b0d0765: Pull complete
b5a0acc6b737: Pull complete
14428c09e432: Pull complete
b47477238ca8: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:a8b493929ca87fdab5114339c80db072f466bc5ddbf8b68687209927f9ee888c
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:3.6.8-alpine3.8
 ---> b6bfe2b71f9d
Step 2/9 : ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 ---> Running in 543dd0936d49
Removing intermediate container 543dd0936d49
 ---> cad826cdc83b
Step 3/9 : RUN apk update     && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev     && apk add libsm6 libxext6 libxrender1
 ---> Running in 076d905f2382
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.8.4-253-g5ea4a0536e [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main]
v3.8.4-253-g5ea4a0536e [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community]
OK: 9571 distinct packages available
(1/17) Upgrading musl (1.1.19-r10 -> 1.1.19-r11)
(2/17) Installing binutils (2.30-r6)
(3/17) Installing gmp (6.1.2-r1)
(4/17) Installing isl (0.18-r0)
(5/17) Installing libgomp (6.4.0-r9)
(6/17) Installing libatomic (6.4.0-r9)
(7/17) Installing pkgconf (1.5.3-r0)
(8/17) Installing libgcc (6.4.0-r9)
(9/17) Installing mpfr3 (3.1.5-r1)
(10/17) Installing mpc1 (1.0.3-r1)
(11/17) Installing libstdc++ (6.4.0-r9)
(12/17) Installing gcc (6.4.0-r9)
(13/17) Installing python3 (3.6.9-r1)
(16/17) Installing build-deps (0)
(17/17) Upgrading musl-utils (1.1.19-r10 -> 1.1.19-r11)
Executing busybox-1.28.4-r3.trigger
OK: 192 MiB in 48 packages
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  libsm6 (missing):
    required by: world[libsm6]
    required by: world[libxext6]
  libxrender1 (missing):
    required by: world[libxrender1]
The command '/bin/sh -c apk update     && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev     && apk add libsm6 libxext6 libxrender1' returned a non-zero code: 3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49905104/error-when-installing-python3-packages-in-alpine

Comment: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages has a search interface.  Or you can use a Debian/Ubuntu-based image instead.

Comment: @David Maze The search interface does not list those packages. Also, the size is very large which is the main reason.

Comment: @Clemens Kaserer Not a duplicate.

Comment: @Yahyaa, I second David's comment. I recommend that you use another image such as debian/ubuntu. Once you have multiple containers utilizing the same base the size is not that important anymore due to the fact that containers reuse the image layers that they have in common.

Comment: @ckaserer I shall try with the ubuntu/debian images.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace

```bash
apk add libsm6 libxext6
```

with

```bash
apk add libsm-dev libxrender libxext-dev
```